# Visualforce after excel file export, broken file name issue

Tags: visualforce, lightning, community, salesforce1-app, data-export

Now im trying to appoint an excel export name dynamically like this. but after export this source of code,

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="registerForm" sidebar="false" contentType="application/vnd.ms-excel#{!CurrentAccountName}_{!TODAY()}.xls" language="en_us" title="" cache="false" action="{!doInit}">

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
```

it returns this file name.. but english did go well but, other UTF-8 characters are all broken. also {!Account.Name} doesn't work too.. CurrentAccountName is string as well.

[image]

how i solve this issue?

Thanks a lot!

```
public with sharing class registerForm {
  public String currentRecordId;
  public String currentAccountName{get; set;}
  public String currentYear{get; set;}
  public String currentMonth{get; set;}
  public String currentDay{get; set;}

  public Account objAcc {get; set;}
  public PageReference pageRef {get; set;}

public CustomerRegFormExpController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) 
{
    Account temp = (Account)controller.getRecord();
    currentRecordId = temp.Id;
    pageRef = new PageReference('/'+currentRecordId);
}
```

...

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the code for the `registerForm` class? That'll probably be important in getting you an answer.

Comment: @DerekF I've added controller on the body. Thanks for reply